# Is this a bug in grep -P ? (I seem to be getting too many matches appearing)

Tags: windows, command-line, regex, grep, gnuwin32

Here is a file I have  http://www.zen76171.zen.co.uk/blahsomefile1

It's a text file about 1.18MB in size

Looking at how many matching lines I get

With -P

```
C:\blah>grep -P "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | wc -l
72383
```

Without -P

```
C:\blah>grep "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | wc -l
51814
```

There shouldn't be a difference whether -P or without -P, but there is. The -P is matching too much.

With this test I should get the same figure 'cos i'm saying list every line that matches xyz and within that output list every line that matches xyz. It works without -P.

Without -P nothing funny happening.

```
C:\blah>grep "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | wc -l
51814

C:\blah>grep "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | grep "[^J]*J" | wc -l
51814
```

With -P things happening that should not be happening..

```
C:\blah>grep -P "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | wc -l
72383


C:\blah>grep -P "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | grep -P "[^J]*J" | wc -l
72229
```

If I do `grep -P "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | more`

I see it is matching things it shouldn't match, like the line that reads `txxxraabcAA`  which contains no J.

```
txxxJbmmabcraabc
txxxraabcAA
txxxJxmmabcHaabc
```

Computer is running gnuwin32 grep

```
C:\blah>where grep
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe
```

grep version is 2.5.4

```
C:\blah>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -V
GNU grep 2.5.4

Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


C:\blah>
```

**UPDATE**

Interestingly cygwin's one is much later.. and doesn't have the bug

```
C:\blah\aeea2\a\a\a\a>c:\cygwin\bin\grep -P "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | wc -l
51814

C:\blah>c:\cygwin\bin\grep -V
/usr/bin/grep (GNU grep) 2.21
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.

C:\blah>
```

gnuwin32 grep is still on 2.5.4 , a very old version.

Note- file is also available [from wetransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/4e0bd2052f954d553d3f1d43c26c022120161017003749/15dca3a37ee2c415e9a790915a2d802620161017003749/a3d43a) and downloadable [from ge.tt](http://ge.tt/8Ur7obf2) with eg firefox.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem on Linux using the current version of  GNU grep: 2.26.  You may want to see if you can update your software: [version 2.5.4 dates to 2009](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bug in  grep 2.5.4

If you have a choice between gnuwin32 grep or cygwin grep,  cygwin grep is far more up to date.

-V shows version and year, and that as of writing -

gnuwin32 grep is version `2.5.4` that's  2009. Years behind.

cygwin grep is years ahead of gnuwin32 grep.  `2.21` (that's later than 2.5.4 because 2.21 is not like one arithmetic number with a decimal point) and the year of cygwin's grep is  2014.

```
C:\blah>c:\cygwin\bin\grep -P "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | wc -l
51814

C:\blah>c:\cygwin\bin\grep -P "[^J]*J" blahsomefile1 | c:\cygwin\bin\grep -P "[^J]*J" | wc -l
51814
```

See no error there with cygwin grep which is 2014.

This is not the first time i've run into a bug in gnuwin32 version of grep when the cygwin version of grep was much later and fine.  gnuwin32 seems to be very out of date compared to alternatives.